# Export CSV to ~/Desktop on OS X with Excel Macro

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I'm trying to export a CSV using a macro in Excel on OS X (2015). The code below worked previously...but now it's failing. Unfortunately all the info I'm finding it unique to Windows.

I could define the exact file path but need this to work on any OS X machine so defining the users home directory is important.

```
Sub export_csv()
    ' export csv to ~/Desktop
    user_dir = user_dir + MacScript("(do shell script ""cd ~; pwd "")")
    file_name = user_dir & "/Desktop/excel_export.csv"

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=file_name, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is, that i don't have any OS X to test it. But i think one Problem can be if there are to many Sheets in your Workbook.

```
Sub CSV()
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

Dim strDirectory As String
Dim strCurWB As String
Dim longCurFor As Long

strCurWB = ThisWorkbook.FullName
longCurFor = ThisWorkbook.FileFormat
' Store current details for the workbook

'get Path for User Desktp
strDirectory = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop") & "\"
'Loop though each Sheet in the Workbook
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Sheets(ws.Name).Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strDirectory & ThisWorkbook.Name & "-" & ws.Name & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
Next

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strCurWB, FileFormat:=longCurFor
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

I hope This Code Example can Help you and you can take some over to the OSX.

Comment: I get `Run-time error '429': ActiveX component can't create object`

Comment: @bryan can you open a new Quetsion and Poste your Code?

Comment: @bryan Where do you get the Error? And Please Open a new Question

Comment: @bryan replace 'CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop") & "\"' with the path you want to have the CSV